# How to wait Firestore completed and then return boolean result?

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I want to returning True or False when document in collections is exists or not. But it's always return false.

```
if (checkItemDeleted(post)) {
   // true, item still there
} else {
  // false, item deleted
}
```

```
boolean result = false;
private boolean checkItemDeleted(Post post) {
        mPostsCollection
                .document(post.itemID)
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        if (task.getResult().exists()) {
                            // document exists
                            result = true;
                        } else {
                            // document not exists
                            result = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
        return result;
    }
```

I'm still learning, thanks for help.

Comment: You cannot wait for data that is asynchronously loaded. Code that needs the data need to be inside the completion listener, or be called from there, or use Kotlin's `await`.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the result before the get call is done. Don't forget that is async.

Try using async and await instead of the complete listener.